# Jquery text animation, tween or shaping from one to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, jquery-animate

I google it out a lot and I did not find anything that would fit my needs. I was wondering is it possible to animate text with Jquery so that (for example) on mouse over it would change to  some different text. The simplest example:

I have text which says `GOGL`

On mouse over/hover it would change with some nice animation to `GOOGLE`

and on mouse out it would change back to `GOGL`

Is there maybe some great jQuery plugin for something like that or maybe different javascript library?

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/ you can tweek it for your needs (since you don't need scrolling)

Comment: you want something Like this http://jsfiddle.net/CqSne/ ?

Comment: Yea, Something like that would fit my needs... Only I would add some animation to that so it would look 'fancier'... But this is as good as answer to my question so please write an answer so I could accept it :) Thank you

Comment: @dzordz added answer with new demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CqSne/1/)

```
$('#test').hover(function () {
    $(this).text('GOOGLE').stop(true, true).animate({
        width: "65px"
    }, 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        width: "45px"
    }, 500).text('GOGL');
});
```

[Old DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CqSne/)